# Netlogo: getting agents to link if variables values are the same

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to get two breeds of agents (xagents and yagents) to check to see if the value of a variable is the same when they move within one of xagents' radius. Then they should link.

When I try the code below, they link but when I inspect the values of the linked agents, the variable values are not equal; they should not be linking.  The problem procedure is at the end of the code. Any ideas why this is?

When I can move past this part, I want the agents to change the value of another variable, but only if they have the same value as VAR1 (hence the link).

```
breed [xagents xagent]
breed [yagents yagent]
turtles-own  [var1]

to setup
 clear-all
 resize-world -20 20 -20 20
 setup-patches
 setup-turtles
 reset-ticks
end

to
  setup-patches
  ask patches [set pcolor gray ]
end

to
  setup-turtles
  set-default-shape xagents "circle 3"
create-xagents 10
[
  set color white
  set size 2
  set var1 random-normal 5 1
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
]
  set-default-shape yagents "circle 3"
  create-yagents 20
  [
    set color blue
    set size 2
    set var1 random-normal 5 1
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
end

to go
  move-xagents
  move-yagents
  ask xagents [communicate]
  tick
end

to move-xagents
  ask xagents [
   rt random 50
   lt random 50
 forward 1
  ]
end

to move-yagents
  ask yagents [
   rt random 50
   lt random 50
 forward 1
]
    end
   ;;THIS IS THE PROBLEM 
    to communicate
      ask xagents in-radius 1 with [var1 = [var1] of myself]
      [create-links-with other yagents-here 
        [
         set color white
         set thickness 0.1
        ]
        ]
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here that might be causing you problems. First:

```
set var1 random-normal 5 1
```

If you need have matches occur, the likelihood that two agents will share the value from `random-normal` is extremely low- it returns a float value:

```
observer> show random-normal 5 1
observer: 4.051232264359846
```

Choose another way to select values for your `var1` (eg `random-poisson`, or `one-of [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]`) or you will not get matches. The only reason your original code was giving links was because `other xagents` was not included in your `to communicate` code block (see below).

```
   ask xagents in-radius 1 with [var1 = [var1] of myself]
```

Here you should use `other xagents` or you will include the asking agent, not just the other ones `in-radius 1`.

```
      [create-links-with other yagents-here 
        ...
```

So here, you have already used the conditional to select the `xagents` that you would like to form a link, but the same conditional is not applied to the `yagents` side. So, you were getting `xagents` forming links with any `yagents-here`. To fix that, just make sure that the `yagents` must also have the `var1` that you're after, something like:

```
to communicate
  ask other xagents in-radius 3 with [var1 = [var1] of myself]
  [create-links-with yagents in-radius 3 with [var1 = 2 ]
    [
      set color white
      set thickness 0.1
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!!! Is there any way to limit the number of times agents link?  Say I want to stop an xagent linking to anymore yagents after it reaches five links.

Comment: That's a separate question — please open a new question to ask it.